# Внести данные в БД без редиректа Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Вот такой синтаксис формы для вноса в БД:

```html
<form action="/rastvor/submit" method="post">
```

Это в роутах прописал:

```html
Route::post('/rastvor/submit','RastvorController@submit');
```

В итоге получается, что меня редиректит по этому пути "/rastvor/submit", по которому собсна ничего нет. Данные заполняются во всплывающем окне, то есть мне редиректа никакого не надо (обновления страницы тоже). Необходимо только внести данные в БД и просто закрыть это всплывающее окно после этого, без обновления/перенаправления.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: для этого используется ajax. Отправляйте запросы без перезагрузки страницы с помощью js

Comment: так поменяйте на `GET`